# How can I know if geocoder result was just a match in city name?

Tags: ruby, google-geocoder

I'm using Geocoder gem with Google lookup. I'm having a hard time filtering matches.

My code is:

```
  geocoded_by :complete_address, params: {
                      region: 'UY',
                      components: { country: 'UY' }
                    }
```

I only want results in a certain country (Uruguay). If I look up an address just like that it finds no results. (For example `Hernani 1570`). So, I had to search appending the city name, so that's why now I search by `Hernani 1570, Montevideo` and only then I would find a match.

The problem is that if I search for `this is not a real address, Montevideo` I find a match (partial but still) which is the center of the city. I don't want to remove all partial matches, so, is there a way to find out if the match I got was just a match in the city name or if it actually was a match by that street address?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you add a link for the gem you are using? A small working code example would be great too.

Comment: Sure gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.7'
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: Playing with the gem, I am getting a key on `results.first.data['partial_match']` that points to a value of true when there's a partial match. The key isn't there when you give your full address example. If you were to give just 'Montevedeo' it also doesn't return a partial match because it located exactly what you were looking for. If you wanted to filter that out with partials, I would look at the `'types'` key, as the array it points to `['route']` when a street address was given and `["country", "political"]` or `["locality", "political"]` otherwise. Hope that helps.

Comment: I will try it and let you know but I think it will help. If it does you should consider writing as answer.